# How to add multiple Y-Values to one X-Value in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, axis, oxyplot

[image]I need to add several DataPoints with three y-Values and one y-Value. Setting multiple yaxiskeys does not work.
OxyPlots DataPoint only accepts two values (x,y)

I've already tried adding multiple DataPoints with the same x-Value...didnt work fine

```
plot.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y));
plot.YAxisKey = "y";
plot.XAxisKey = "x";

plot.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y1));
plot.YAxisKey = "y1";

plot.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y2));
plot.YAxisKey = "y2";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Some code will help, what you have tryed for example.

Comment: What is the problem, the points are not(correctly) painted? the labels aren't (correctly) painted? Be more specific on what fails and the behaviour you want to achieve please.

Comment: I don't need three points, I always need one point

Comment: Now I understand you. Much better with the image.

Comment: Check this out, I think this is what you are looking for: http://discussion.oxyplot.org/topic/490177-tracker-format-for-custom-data-points/

Comment: no? - that's also about one point with two values

Comment: But you can add the other 2 values on the tracker. Where do you want to see the values? I am assuming you do not want to draw a 4 dimensional point... :)

Comment: Yes I want to draw a 4d point in my plot not only showing in the tracker. I need to check this again :)

Comment: I think that oxyplot doesn't handle more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I think that I've found it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1075272/Multi-line-Tracker-for-OxyPlot